# redux-thunk and async/await actions: how to combine them all?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await, redux-thunk

The following piece of code is one of my actions and actually works.

```
export const loadChannelList = () => { 
    return async (dispatch) => {

        dispatch ({
            type: CHANNEL_LIST_LOADING
        });

        try {
            const response  = await fetch('<my server url>');
            const responseJson = await response.json();

            dispatch ({
                type: CHANNEL_LIST_LOADING_OK,
                payload: "ok" // response.json()
            });

        } catch(error) {
            dispatch ({
                type: CHANNEL_LIST_LOADING_FAILED,
                payload: error
            });
        }
    };
}
```

In a component, I use this in this way:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (this.props.connectionStatus != 'ok' 
            && nextProps.connectionStatus == 'ok'
           ) {
            this.props.loadChannelList();
        }
}
```

I ask you: **is this the right way to use async/await when playing with redux-thunk ?**

I ask this because it's the first time I use async/await in a react-native app in a redux-thunk action and I'd like to be sure that I'm not doing some anti-pattern or other errors

Comment: looks fine to me.  what about it feels strange to you?

Comment: @DavinTryon I ask this because it's the first time I use async/await in a react-native app in a redux-thunk action and I'd like to be sure that I'm not doing some anti-pattern or other errors

Comment: @DavinTryon: no one else reply. Please, transform your comment into an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Shouldn't need an `await` on `const response  = await fetch('<my server url>');`. Only on `const responseJson = await response.json();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need an `await` on:

```
const response  = await fetch('<my server url>');
```

It's only needed on:

```
const responseJson = await response.json();
```

This is because the `fetch` statement returns a `Promise`. So the `await` is only needed to `await` the result of the `Promise`.

Here's a simplified example using some mock functions:

```js
// A fake asynchronous request
function fetch(x) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({
        data: x
      });
    }, 3000);
  });
}

// A fake Dispatch function
function fakeDispatch(theData) {
  console.log(theData);
}

// A function to run on componentDidMount or similar
async function getData(x) {
  const response = fetch(x);
  
  // call the Dispatch
  fakeDispatch(await response);
}

// componentDidMount
console.log('Mounting component...');
getData("some data");
```